# AWS SQS 1 queue 2 subscribers

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-sqs

I'm running into a problem. I'm trying to use a single SQS queue with two long polling nodeJS instances. The problem I'm facing, is when I put a new message into the queue, BOTH instances pull the same messages immediately. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? My goal is to eventually have a NodeJS processing farm where each instance will pull a unique message from the queue and perform processing.

Below is my code for my SQS listener:

```js
console.log("Checking SQS Queue");
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let sqs = new aws.SQS();
        let params = {
            AttributeNames: [
                "SentTimeStamp"
            ],
            MaxNumberOfMessages: 1,
            MessageAttributeNames: [
                "All"
            ],
            QueueUrl: SQS_URL,
            WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
            VisibilityTimeout: 0
        };
        sqs.receiveMessage(params, (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                console.log("Error: ",err);
                reject(err);
            } else if (data.Messages) {
                resolve(data);
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a higher [VisibilityTimeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html), at least the time it takes to process the message, then it will not visible to other instance after one instance read the message from SQS till VisibilityTimeout value.

Please check the VisibilityTimeout you have set for the queue when you have created it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good call. I had mistaken 0 as "infinite". Bumped up the value and it worked like a charm! Thank you.